# Bootstrap 3 datatable not working with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried this code for re-initializing datatable of Bootstrap 3 for search option. but it's not working for me while call from server side is using AngularJS.The dataTable response invoke from server side(PHP) through Controller.

**"table20"** is response table id.

Thanks advance..

Below is the code for my Controller

```
$scope.update_frame_imgs = function(frame_clrid) {

    //$('#table20').dataTable();
    $http.post("ajax/order_main_table.php").success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.order_main_table=data;
            $('#table20').dataTable().fnDestroy();
            $('#table20').dataTable();

            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                  //alert("Please Try Again..!");
                              });
    }
```

Comment: not working for you is pretty broad, can you be a little more specific? also, why are you using jquery methods in an angular post method?

Comment: i just use that..that's all..any other way else what's wrong with my code..bro